# How to add a modules to an existing apache

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I'm using apache 2.2.15 in production now I want to add some modules like :

```
mod_access_compat.so
mod_allowmethods.so
```

I installed apache with yum in CentOS 6 and I can't switch to any other version.

Comment: You install it and enable automatically.You can configure it.

Comment: @supirady please can you explain more !

Comment: When you install it from yum or rpm packages.That 2 modules will add to apache.I didnt use that 2 modules. I just answered your question.When you compile that 2 modules from source code.You should add it manually to apache.

Comment: This is the problem, i cant find those modules in "apache_dir/modules"

Comment: How did you install that 2 modules? You can find that 2 modules module-name.so when you installed it successfully.By Default Apache on Centos 6 didnt have that 2 modules.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to (nor need to) use `mod_access_compat` with the 2.2 branch – that's the 2.4 module that emulates 2.2's Allow/Deny syntax.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz  what about mod_allowmethods ?

Answer (score 2):

You say you're using apache 2.2.15 in production, and you can't switch to any other version.

That means you're out of luck, as [mod_allowmethods](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_allowmethods.html) is only included in Apache 2.4.x.

So you need to either:

- Compile them from source.
- Upgraded your apache version/installation to something more recent.
- Hope somebody has backported them.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so i did compile from the source the same version 2.2.15 with `./configure --enable-layout=admin --enable-mpms-shared=all --enable-modules=all --enable-mods-shared=all` but when check the modules i can't find bothe `allowmethods` and `access_compat` !

Comment: While I'd love to help it would be easier if you showed error messages, or failure-logs.  When running "`./configure`", then `make`, did you see generated `.so` files with the right filename?  Do you understand that compiling from source will cause you failures in the future - because you'll have binaries installed by the system-package-manager and your source tree?